# While using app.all() i can't serve static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

in route.js if i remove the

```
app.all('*',(req,res,next)=>{
   res.status(404).json({
       status:'failed',
       message:`can't find ${req.originalUrl} url`
   })
})
```

code then the static file is served but if i use this code then my static file is not served.
Please Help!
index.js file

```
const fs=require('fs');
const express=require('express');
const http=require('http');
const url=require('url');
const app=require('./routes/routes.js');
const controllers=require('./controllers/controllers.js');
// ---------------------------------------middleware-end-----------------------------------------------
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// --------------------------------------accessing-static-files-end---------------------------------------
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000,'127.0.0.1',()=>{
    console.log("server started");
//------------------------------------------connection-end--------------------------------------------- 
});
```

route.js file

```
const express=require('express');

const app=express();

const controllers=require('./../controllers/controllers.js');

// -------------------requiring-modules----------------------------------

const review_route=express.Router();

// ------------------making-routes---------------------------------------

app.use('/series',review_route);

review_route.route('/').get(controllers.replace_template);

app.all('*',(req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(404).json({
        status:'failed',
        message:`can't find ${req.originalUrl} url`
    })
})

module.exports=app;
```

Comment: Makes sense. `app.all('*')` comes before `app.use(express.static())`, so any route matches `('*')` first. Put it last in your code.

Comment: Thankyou sir. its working now